# Hibernate call of a PostgreSQL stored procedure having a TIMESTAMP parameter type

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-boot

I have a `PostgreSQL` database in which I created the following stored procedure :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION saveOrUpdateTicket(param1 bytea, p_date timestamp, param3 INTEGER) RETURNS Integer AS $$

        DECLARE
            ....
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I wanted to call this stored procedure from my Java backend using `StoredProcedureQuery` of **Hibernate**. Bellow the declaration :

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = msidEntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("saveOrUpdateTicket");

storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, byte[].class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, java.util.Date.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(1, key);
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(2, new Date());
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(3, val);

storedProcedureQuery.execute();
```

But when I execute my code under unit testing, I have the following error :

```
Hibernate: 
    {call saveOrUpdateTicket(?,?,?)}
2016-11-24 15:23:01.987  WARN 13456 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
2016-11-24 15:23:01.988 ERROR 13456 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: function saveorupdateticket(bytea, unknown, integer) does not exist
  IndiceÂ : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  PositionÂ : 15
```

Why Hibernate try to call `saveorupdateticket(bytea, unknown, integer)` instead of `saveorupdateticket(bytea,timestamp without time zone,integer)` ?

*PS: I tested with `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.TimeStamp` with no success !*

---

I'm using :

- **Spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE (Hibernate 5.0.9.Final and I added hibernate-java8)**
- **PostgreSQL 9.4.1209.jre7**

Thank you !

Comment: You should call it using a simple SELECT statement: `select saveOrUpdateTicket(....)` No need for a StoreProcedureQuery. But if you do, you need to register the second parameter with `java.sql.Timestamp`, not `java.util.Date` and you also need to _pass_ a `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: I tested with Timestamp  but the error is the same. Hibernate try to call the stored procedure with unknown parameter instead of Timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem that was due to missing schema. My stored procedure was under the schema `mySchema` and Hibernate tried to find it under the `default` schema. I had to specify the schema in stored procedure declaration like this :

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = msidEntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("mySchema.saveOrUpdateTicket");
```

And everything works fine !

Comment: Alternatively you can set the `search_path` for your DB user so that you don't have to fully qualify all names.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(2, new Date(), TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: I tested it with no success.